# Is it possible to prompt user with simple html/css from nodejs and return data on submission?

Tags: node.js

One way is to start whole server open local host page and wait for response. but I was wondering it's possible to create simple popup and read input and send input etc.

Scenario: a web **scraper** that backs up hacker news comments, you put credentials, it logs in, scrape, and save it. All of this happens locally. Nothing online. Nothing public. Right now user would have to input stuff inside terminal/cmd which is not great experience for non devs.

Or lets say there is some node script that needs human input, quick to categorize data. you type `node app.js` it runs, opens a popup, you select settings, click next, next.. finally submit.. data gets returned to node script.

Comment: You question is way too open ended, it is going to get closed. But yes, that is what web pages do, they present forms to the user and send data back to the server.

Comment: ill add details

Comment: found something close https://github.com/bat-tomr/dialog-node